# Why am I getting an error that says string does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, .net

I have the simple method below:

```
        public static bool IsErrorMessage(String error)
    {
        var isErrorMessage = error.Left(40).Contains("ErrorMessage",StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
        return isErrorMessage;
    }
```

But I getting an error that says string does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and VS wants to use System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains instead.

Using .NET Framework 4.5, C#, VS 2010 and of course I have a using System directive.

Comment: What is that `Left` method and what does it return?

Comment: Left method is not a .net framework method; please give us the method signature including its return

Comment: This shouldn't be the way you handle errors, by the way. That is what `Exception`s are for. What if the `error` is actually `"This is not an ErrorMessage."`? Is that considered as an `ErrorMessage`?

Comment: Left is an extension method that returns a string.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Maybe the OP is parsing a log file looking for error messages.

Comment: @mikez A log file should have a structure. Checking for the first 40 characters to see if it contains `"ErrorMessage"` doesn't give me a sense of structure. This also leaves a lot of room for mistakes (typos, etc).

Comment: If an exception occurred, it is serialized and returned to the client as a JSON string. If not, the returned JSON string is data. The routine checks for ErrorMessage in the first 40 characters and there is no data that would contain the text ErrorMessage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no overload of `String.Contains` that takes two arguments. If you want to use a `StringComparison`, use `IndexOf`:

```
bool isErrorMessage = error.Left(40).IndexOf("ErrorMessage", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) > -1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In retrospect, that should have been obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's preferring the LINQ extension method due to the two parameters, since String::Contains only has one param.

I think you need to flesh out your extension methods to discover the problem.  Here is a compiling example that should get you started:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Left(this string s, int count)
    {
        // your method
        return "";
    }
    public static bool Contains(this string s, string contains, StringComparison comp)
    {
        // your method
        return true;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static bool IsErrorMessage(String error)
    {
        var isErrorMessage = error.Left(40).Contains("ErrorMessage", StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
        return isErrorMessage;
    }
}
```